# Collision detection inside the same ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collision-detection

After searching around over the course of a few days, I have not found a solution. I have an `ArrayList` of collision elements that I want to iterate over and calculate collisions for. I have made several similar attempts, but I am currently stumped.

Collision method (called once a game-tick)

```
public void iterateCollision()
{ 
    if(iterateBoxes)
    {   
        if(iterateBoxes)
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<boxPool.size();i++) 
        {   
            for(int j=i+1;j<boxPool.size();j++)
            {
                if(!(boxPool.get(i).equals(boxPool.get(j))) && checkCollision(boxPool.get(i), boxPool.get(j)))
                {
                    boxPool.get(i).colliding = true;
                    boxPool.get(j).colliding = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the collision detection method for those of you who would like to review it:

```
public boolean checkCollision(BaseAABB box1, BaseAABB box2)
{
    //This is just to get the center vector of the bounding boxes.
    Vector2f c1 = getAABBCenter(box1);
    Vector2f c2 = getAABBCenter(box2);

    if(Math.abs(c1.x - c2.x) > (box1.width + box2.width)) return false;
    if(Math.abs(c1.y - c2.y) > (box1.height + box2.height)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is likely a problem with your `checkCollision` method. Can you post that as well?

Comment: Also, how specifically is it not working?

Comment: I am sure the checkCollision() method works(I've run multiple tests), as to how it doesnt work? Well... just that. Absolutely nothing happens

Comment: Then perhaps iterateBoxes is false or the value of `colliding` is being used incorrectly? The code you posted here looks fine to me.

Comment: That's why its starting to get to me! All my attempts end up doing the same thing. Colliding is just a boolean that I am temporarily drawing the value of to test(if the players box is colliding) And currently no where in my code does iterateBoxes change. I made sure the whole method is actually being called as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to add a condition that `i != j`
2. I suspect that you should replace the following condition:

---

```
boxPool.get(i) != boxPool.get(j)
```

with:

```
!boxPool.get(i).equals(boxPool.get(j))
```

---

Further, there's no need to double loop over *all* the elements, you can always start with `j = i + 1` and then you don't have to check that `i != j`:

```
    for(int i=0;i<boxPool.size();i++) 
    {   
        //         V  
        for(int j=i+1;j<boxPool.size();j++) // <-- this line has changed! 
        {
            if(boxPool.get(i) != boxPool.get(j) && checkCollision(boxPool.get(i),   boxPool.get(j)))
            {
                boxPool.get(i).colliding = true;
                boxPool.get(j).colliding = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree with @alfasin, but make sure the size of your ArrayList isn't too big - or this will take a long time.  Came across similar code 2 days ago, where the array could literally be any size. It just so happened that my data was n=15,000, which meant the inner loop executed n*(n-1)/2 times - ie approx 112,492,500. PS. The whole code ended up being redundant anyway.

Comment: In effect, `boxPool.get(i) != boxPool.get(j)` checks that `i!=j`, assuming that all elements of the ArrayList are unique.

Comment: @FlightOdyssey you're right, it does the same in effect (and in a very twisted way ;)

Comment: At one point in time, I tried just that! Almost to the point of exact code. However, still no luck! Ill replace my code with this for the time being though.

Comment: @BoltReel since we don't see all your code it's a bit difficult to debug. There could be another two points of failure: one that I already mentioned (using `equals` instead of `==`), did you implement `equals` in your class ? and another point: the implementation of `checkCollision()`

Comment: Me being the newbie I am to this site, I was afraid of posting irrelevant code. However, I have added the collision method. Also i'm not entirely sure on what you are asking about the implementation of equals?

Comment: @BoltReel you're trying to compare between objects that return from `boxPool.get(i)` for example. Using `==` checks if this is the exact same object (the pointers point to same location in the heap) while `equals` checks if the objects are "logically" equals (as long as you implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your class)